# How to color bars of a distribution plot using gradient colors?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I have the following dataframe `df`:

```
time_diff   avg_trips_per_day
0.450000    1.0
0.483333    1.0
0.500000    1.0
0.516667    2.0
0.533333    5.0
```

Then I create a distribution plot as follows `ax = sns.distplot(df['time_diff'],hist="true"`.

I want to color the bars using a gradient: darker colors should be assigned to the values of higher probability.

I tried to do it this way, but it did not work:

```
norm = plt.Normalize(df["time_diff"].values.min(), df["time_diff"].values.max())
colors = plt.cm.YlGnBu(norm(df_imh_unique["time_diff"])) 
ax = sns.distplot(df['time_diff'],hist="true", color=colors)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code you are trying to colorize the bars according to the data values themselves. However, a histogram shows the frequency of the values inside bins. You thus need to use the frequency to determine the color of the bars.

This is easier to understand when separating the histogramming and the plotting.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = np.random.rayleigh(size=30)

hist, edges = np.histogram(data)

norm = plt.Normalize(hist.min(), hist.max())
colors = plt.cm.YlGnBu(norm(hist)) 

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.bar(edges[:-1], hist, np.diff(edges), color=colors, ec="k", align="edge")

plt.show()
```

[image]

You may set the bins in the call to `np.histogram`, e.g. for 0.1 large bins, you'd use

```
bins = np.arange(0, data.max()+0.1, 0.1)
hist, edges = np.histogram(data, bins=bins)
```

Since seaborn distplot combines the two steps of histogramming and plotting, setting the colors of the bars would only be possible *after* creating the plot. This is of course not optimal, but for completeness, a solution which uses an existing `distplot` may look like this:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

data = np.random.rayleigh(size=30)

ax = sns.distplot(data)

vals = np.array([rec.get_height() for rec in ax.patches])
norm = plt.Normalize(vals.min(), vals.max())
colors = plt.cm.YlGnBu(norm(vals))

for rec, col in zip(ax.patches, colors):
    rec.set_color(col)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I cannot resize this plot if i use `plt.figure(figsize=(14,8))` at the beginning. It's always small.

Comment: Also I need to maintain my bins of the size `25`. In my code I use `plt.xticks(np.arange(min(df_day_route_veh_counts['time_diff']), max(df_day_route_veh_counts['time_diff'])+100, 25.0))`. How can i fit this approach to your code?

Comment: `plt.subplots(figsize=(14,8))` sets the figure size. `plt.xticks` does not set the bin size. It sets the location of the ticks on the axes. But it will work in this code as well. If you want to change the bin size of the histogram, you need to use the `bins` argument of `np.histogram`.

Comment: Should I create these bins manually? Cannot I just say that each bin should be equal to 0.1? For example, the combination of `sns.distplot(df['time_diff'],hist="true"` and `plt.xticks` creates bins automatically according to the distance defined by `plt.xticks`.

Comment: You may either specify the number of bins or the bin edges. The latter case is shown in the updated answer.

Comment: `plt.xticks` does not know anything about your distplot, therefore it cannot create the bins automatically. If they appear to match, this is pure coincidence. Try other data and it will not fit any more.